# Why is the second linux system I install unable to access the Internet?

Tags: wireless, dual-boot, ethernet

I am attempting to run Zorin OS 7 alongside Ubuntu on my laptop, but whichever OS I install second, does not have internet access (will not work with ethernet or wifi).  So I was wondering if this was an issue because both OS are ubuntu based or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Here you can see how to put 145 OS's on 1 system: http://forums.justlinux.com/showthread.php?147959-How-to-install-and-boot-145-operating-systems-in-a-PC Oh and 2 diff. OS's have their own settings related to wireless and wired. They are separate instances unless you use virtualbox (in that case the system inside it needs to be adjusted).

Comment: It sounds like your *real* question is "why is the second linux system I install unable to access the Internet".  If so you should edit your question to reflect that instead of asking a question you already know the answer to, since you already have installed them both on the same drive.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I changed to question to reflect my real question.  Not sure if maybe the OS is not installing correctly and therefore the ethernet does not work on startup.  Tough problem to fix since I cannot install any drivers without internet access.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. When you are going through the install options, just be sure to choose "Install alongside Ubuntu" when asked how you want to install. Ubuntu should ask how you want to partition. If you aren't particularly experienced with Linux, I recommend just sticking with the default options. Ubuntu should do the rest from then on, and you can choose to boot whichever version you want at startup.